# Would this QChangesOpacityEffect usage cause a potential memory leak? (but only way to force repaint...)

Tags: c++, qt

So, I am working with some QWidgets inside a QMdiArea, and i want to play with the opacity og a graphicview inside the QWidgets with a dial, using the QGraphicsOpacityEffect.

This is the slot that receives the dial signal to set the new opacity:

```
void MainWindow::changeWindow1Transparency(int dialValue)
{
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect* op = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->graphicsView); //Potential memory leak here
    op->setOpacity(qreal(dialValue)/255);
    ui->graphicsView->setGraphicsEffect(op);
    ui->graphicsView->repaint();
}
```

This is the only way i've managed to make the opacity change immediately when turning the dial. But I fear that this might cause a memory leak because of the new constantly creating new effects.

I have tried to set this `QGraphicOpacityEffect *op` as an attribute of the class. But then, when I turn the dial, the opacity doesn't change immediately but only when I move the window around the QMdiArea. The same happens when calling the `QGraphicsView->GraphicsEffects()`.. Any ideas on why this is happening? how could I prevent the memory leak and at the same time force that the opacity changes immediately with the dial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *shouldn't* be a memory leak as long as you pass a parent object to your QGraphicsOpacityEffect **or** set a widget with the effect.

The way you've set it up `ui->graphicsView->setGraphicsEffect(op)`, According to [`QWidget::setGraphicsEffect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect):

> Sets effect as the widget's effect. If there already is an effect installed on this widget, QWidget will delete the existing effect before installing the new effect.

You've got yourself a guarantee that the intermediate objects will be deleted. With regards to the final GraphicsEffect, as your `ui->graphicsView` widget is destroyed, so does the GraphicsOpacityEffect (see [Qt Object Trees and Ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html)).

---

As for forcing the opacity changes to your dial, try adding `repaint();` to your slot. This will repaint your entire widget. (And after that, also try `parentWidget()->repaint()` as the parent sometimes needs a little nudging.)

---

As Jeremy Friesner mentions in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155999/would-this-qchangesopacityeffect-usage-cause-a-potential-memory-leak-but-only#comment95143538_54156339) and as you've tried before, it may be more efficient to set `QGraphicOpacityEffect *op` as a member of the class, calling `op->setOpacity(x)` in your slot without having to create a new effect each time the slot is triggered. Keep in mind the repaint semantics above.

Comment: ... all that said, it would probably be more efficient to only allocate the `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` object once, and then on the second and further calls to `changeWindow1Transparency()`, simply call `setOpacity()` on the single `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` object (instead of replacing it with a new object)

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try to play with the repaint, but i feel relieved knowing there is no memory leak :)

Comment: WWell, I have tried to do the repaint for both the widget and the parentwidget but it still does not refresh with the dial (which sets the opacity), but after moving or resizing the window. Any idea?

Comment: @VíctorDelosSantos We don’t know how you’ve got your project set up and may need an mcve. Please edit your question and provide one (even if it’s just setting up an ui file). Thanks :)